# Do STL containers do smart deallocation like shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Are STL containers smart like `shared_ptr`?

They do deallocate on their own when out of scope, but what about assignment operations?

```
vector<int> aa(9);
...fill aa...
vector<int> bb;
aa = bb;
```

Did the assignment operation deallocate properly everything that was in `aa`?

Comment: Are you asking if the standard library has built-in memory leaks?

Comment: Yes standard classes manage themselves.  That is a big part of using them.

Comment: It might not actually deallocate in this case. It may just retain the capacity of 9 and change the size to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment of standard library containers is entirely safe, *if* (in each case) assignment of the item type is safe.

This is part of the reason for preferentially using standard library containers whereever practical: they're safe.

Containers don't leak memory but if you hold on to a container after it has contained a large number of items, the container might hold on to allocated memory, its *capacity*, in order to efficiently reuse it rather than later allocating new memory (which is costly to do). This can give some of the same symptoms as a real memory leak, and in a way it can be regarded as a kind of leak. Since containers are safe, when a container becomes empty or near empty you can easily trim the capacity down by calling **`shrink_to_fit`**, which is non-binding, or by **`swap`**-ping the contents with a temporary instance of the same container type, either empty or with copies of the items you want to keep.

---

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>        // std::swap
#include <iostream>         // ...
#include <utility>          // std::move
#include <vector>           // std::vector    
using namespace std;

class Item
{
private:
    int id_;

    Item( Item const& ) = delete;
    auto operator=( Item const& ) -> Item& = delete;

public:
    auto operator=( Item&& other ) -> Item&
    { id_ = other.id_; other.id_ = 0; return *this; }

    ~Item()
    { if( id_ != 0 ) { wcout << "Destroyed #" << id_ << ".\n"; } }

    Item( int id )
        : id_( id )
    { wcout << "Created #" << id_ << ".\n"; }

    Item( Item&& other )
        : id_( other.id_ )
    { other.id_ = 0; }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    vector<Item> v;
    for( int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i ) { v.push_back( Item( i ) ); }

    wcout << "capacity with 7 items: " << v.capacity() << "\n";
    v.erase( v.begin() + 2, v.end() );
    wcout << "capacity with " << v.size() << " items: " << v.capacity() << "\n";
    // Forcibly reduce the capacity. Can't just copy since Item isn't copyable:
    {
        vector<Item> copy;
        for( Item& o : v ) { copy.push_back( move( o ) ); }     // Move items over.
        swap( v, copy );
    }
    wcout << "Capacity after forced reduce: " << v.capacity() << endl;
}
```

The specific details of the result depends on the compiler and options used when building the program.

But e.g. with MinGW g++ 5.1.0:

```
Created #1.
Created #2.
Created #3.
Created #4.
Created #5.
Created #6.
Created #7.
capacity with 7 items: 8
Destroyed #3.
Destroyed #4.
Destroyed #5.
Destroyed #6.
Destroyed #7.
capacity with 2 items: 8
Capacity after forced reduce: 2
Destroyed #1.
Destroyed #2.
```

Answer (score 5):

> Did the assignment operation deallocate properly everything that was in `aa`?

All the objects that were contained are properly destroyed and the assignment is safe.

The memory is not necessarily deallocated. `aa` may reuse the memory for the objects that were copied from `bb`. The deallocation will happen when `aa` is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

For each existing element of the vector before the assignment, the object's destructor will be called. This is independent of any memory allocation that happens inside the container, which is an implementation detail that usually doesn't matter.